# Group by on select not working

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables, my outer select aggregates all those ids which are present in my other table which I have put in where clause. Both tables are generated using wild cards function. following is the query -

```
SELECT count(id), timestamp  FROM (TABLE_QUERY(dataset1, 'expr'))  
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (TABLE_QUERY(dataset1, 'expr')) 
WHERE timestamp < 1414670361836)  ) group by timestamp
```

I get following error -

> Query Failed Error: (L1:56): JOIN (including semi-join) and UNION ALL
>   (comma) may not be combined in a single SELECT statement. Either move
>   the UNION ALL to an inner query or the JOIN to an outer query.

Can someone point me out what is the problem and how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re-phrasing with a query working on public data.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(actor), created_at
FROM (TABLE_QUERY([publicdata:samples], "table_id CONTAINS 'github'"))
WHERE actor IN (
  SELECT actor
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([publicdata:samples], "table_id CONTAINS 'github'"))
  WHERE created_at > '')  
GROUP BY created_at

Error: (L2:1): JOIN (including semi-join) and UNION ALL (comma) may not be combined in a single SELECT statement. Either move the UNION ALL to an inner query or the JOIN to an outer query.
```

This does:

```
SELECT COUNT(actor), created_at
FROM (
  SELECT actor, created_at
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([publicdata:samples], "table_id CONTAINS 'github'"))
)
WHERE actor IN (
  SELECT actor
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([publicdata:samples], "table_id CONTAINS 'github'"))
  WHERE created_at > ''
  LIMIT 100)  
GROUP BY created_at
```

I just moved the

```
  SELECT actor, created_at
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([publicdata:samples], "table_id CONTAINS 'github'"))
```

to an inner query.